# Java ArrayList Casting Issue

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList in Java which is full of int's. I am accessing it through get method. Now, I need array list int objects as ints to perform some operations. So, what I am doing is,

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(arraylist.get(position).toString()) + 100 ...
```

Is there any-other nice way to do it (means efficiently) ?

Comment: "I have an ArrayList in Java which is full of int's". No, you don't. You can't store primitives in an `ArrayList`. You have an `ArrayList` of `Integer` objects.

Comment: @Jesper, Thanks. Sorry, I said it wrongly. I mean int objects.

Comment: No, you mean `Integer` objects. `int` is a primitive type; an `int` is not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Java are you using? Since Java 1.5 the 'autoboxing' feature should take care of this for you.

```
int i = arrayList.get(position) + 100;
```

Comment: You haven't shown us where your array is instantiated. If you have it set up as an array of Integers this should work.

Comment: Ok sorry. I have not declared it as INT.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess that was an assumption on my part.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - don't convert to a string and back!

```
int i = arrayList.get(position).intValue() + 100;
```

Or using auto-unboxing:

```
int i = arrayList.get(position) + 100;
```

As noted in comments, I'm happy with auto-unboxing when the expression is just used in assignment expression (or as a method argument) - when it's used as part of an arithmetic expression, I generally prefer to make it explicit.

(Note that your list will be full of `Integer` references, not `int` values.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice way to do.

Comment: With auto-unboxing, you can simplify it to `int i = arrayList.get(position) + 100;`

Comment: @GregKopff: While I suspected that would be okay, I wasn't 100% sure it would unbox as part of the arithmetic. I normally only use unboxing directly in assignment - I feel this ends up being clearer. Will add the option though.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.put(1);
myList.put(2);
...
int num = myList.get(index) + 100;
```

Or do whatever you like, collection will contain only Integers so you don't have to convert it. Plus, autoboxing takes care for int->Integer and back.